# Getting null for getelementbyid dynamic generated HTML

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, powerapps

am embedding powerapps form in sharepoint page. i have a dropdown box in powerapps. in sharepoint page based on dropdown value i want to display some code. from below code i want APAC text. am not included divchatbutton html code here.

this is my HTML code which is generated in browser.

```
div data-is-focusable="true" id="react-combobox-view-0" class="label_kohvda-o_O-label_2lsolt" tabindex="9" role="listbox" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" aria-atomic="true" title="Region" aria-live="assertive">

<div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative; display: flex; height: 100%; align-items: stretch;">
<ul style="margin: 0px; padding: 5px; list-style: none; display: flex; overflow: hidden;">
<li class="selectedItem_1og5q2j">
<span class="topTagText_yz2uri-o_O-topTagText_t9v74o-o_O-topTagTextReadonly_ps5463">APAC</span></li></ul></div>

<div class="combobox-view-chevron arrowContainer_1kmq8gc-o_O-container_r2h174-o_O-containerColors_1803dea"></div></div>
```

> this is my javascript code

```
<script>
function runAfterEverythingElse(){   
 var nav = document.getElementById("divChatButton");
       nav.style.display='none';
    GetRegion();
}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("GetRegion");`

function GetRegion(){
        // do whatever you like here
        var myDiv = document.getElementById('react-combobox-view-0');
    var x = myDiv.getElementsByTagName('div');
    var y = x[0].getElementsByTagName('ul');
    var z = y[0].children[0].innerText;
    if(z=="AMER")
    {
         var nav = document.getElementById("divChatButton");
       nav.style.display='block';
    }
    else
    {
         var nav = document.getElementById("divChatButton");
       nav.style.display='none';
    }
        setTimeout(yourFunction, 2000);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following jQuery code for your reference.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myVar;
$(function () {         
    myVar = setInterval(getDropdownValue, 100);
});
function getDropdownValue(){
    if($("div[title='Region'] li[class^='selectedItem']").length>0){
        var region=$("div[title='Region'] li[class^='selectedItem']").text();
        if(region=="AMER"){
            $("#divChatButton").show();
        }else{
            $("#divChatButton").hide();
        }
        clearInterval(myVar);
    }   
}
</script>
```